# Template syntax error - Could not parse the remainder

Tags: jquery, django

Im trying to create a div using Jquery in Django but I get the following error -

Could not parse the remainder: '\'product-images/' from '\'product-images/'

```
$("<div id = product" + i + "left  class = product-cards-left> <a href=\'{% static \'product-images/ " + obj.image_caption +  " \' %}\' data-lightbox=\'image-1\' data-title=\'My caption\''>Image #1</a> </div>").appendTo('#product' + i)
```

Basically I have a id and then following by a "a" tag.

How can I fix this issue?

Latest code:--

```
$("<div id = product" + i + "left  class = product-cards-left>  <a href={\% static \'product-images///" + obj.image_caption + "' \%}\'      >Image #1</a> </div>").appendTo('#product' + i)


<div id="product0left" class="product-cards-left">  <a href="{%" static="" 'product-images="" 10000_books'="" %}'="">Image #1</a> </div>
```

The "/" between the "product-images" and "1000_books" are not being added

Comment: Try this (You dont need to escape `'` unless it is nested): `$("<div id = product" + i + "left  class = 'product-cards-left'> <a href='{{STATIC_URL}}/product-images/{{obj.image_caption}}' data-lightbox='image-1' data-title='My caption'>Image #1</a> </div>").appendTo("#product" + i)
`

Comment: The page is generated using the Jquery..Your syntax looks perfect for HTML...

Comment: Then django tags wont work in jquery pages. What you are trying would not work.

Comment: I have multiple products that needs to be displayed on the page..The products are returned from a ajax call and I generate the pages using Jquery...The static keyword is used to load the pictures from the static webserver...

Comment: I checked this document - http://www.nomadjourney.com/2009/01/using-django-templates-with-jquery-ajax/ - and it looks like we can load the template tags in Jquery..Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using jQuery to build up your pages.
Dom manipulations is extremely heavy and Django is way better/faster in this.

Also I would recommend first splitting your div and link (specially during debugging) :

```
var div = $('<div>', {
  id: 'product' + i + 'left',
  class: 'product-cards-left'
});

$('<a>', {
  href: '{{STATIC_URL}}/product-images/{{obj.image_caption}}',
  'data-lightbox': 'image-1',
  'data-title': 'My caption',
  text: 'Image #1'
}).appendTo(div);

div.appendTo('#product' + i);
```